# What is the most elegant way to display key value pairs using a recursive function with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion, javascript-objects

How can you loop through an object which contains an unknown number of nested objects, strings or arrays. The structure would be similar to:

```
const myObject = {
    name: 'Dan',
    age: 31,
    interests: ['coding', 'asking questions'],
    needsHelp: true,
    nestedData: {
        level1Data: {
            randomNumber: 41,
            anObject: {
                description: 'Nested data'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I'm currently using a function like this for the loop:

```
for (var k in obj) {
  // If object and its not empty
  if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
    // Run function again
    eachRecursive(obj[k]);
  }
  // if something else and not empty
  else {
    if (obj[k] !== null) {
      console.log(typeof obj[k], obj[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

This function loops how I'd like, however I want to list these out in a tabular structure where deep nested arrays/objects are and this is the step I require some help in figuring out.

An example of the HTML table I'd like to output is in the screenshot below:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result from the given object?

Comment: *"list these out in a tabular structure"* Can you please post how that looks like?

Comment: You might  not want to use the word "most" in your question since there probably isn't a single answer we will all agree on, which means your question could get closed for being opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll edit and collate the desired output to make this question clearer.

Comment: @NinaScholz I've added the desired output table.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass an additional `prefix` parameter to each recursive call and attach it to the nested keys. `flatMap` is used to get a flat array of entries instead of nested arrays.

Loop through the entries returned and create a rows of the table

Since you want the entire array to be in a single row, `!Array.isArray(v)` condition is added. If you have array of objects as properties, you can skip that from the `if` condition

```js
const myObject = { name: 'Dan', age: 31, interests: ['coding', 'asking questions'], needsHelp: true, nestedData: { level1Data: { randomNumber: 41, anObject: { description: 'Nested data' } } } };

function getEntries(obj, prefix = '') {
  return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => {
    // if nested values is an object and it is not an array
    if (Object(v) === v && !Array.isArray(v))
      return getEntries(v, `${prefix}${k}.`)
    else
      return [ [`${prefix}${k}`, v] ]
  })
}

/*
console.log( JSON.stringify(getEntries(myObject)) )

// if you want to create a flat object
console.log( 
 Object.fromEntries(getEntries(myObject)) 
)
*/

// creating rows of the table
getEntries(myObject).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  document.querySelector("table").innerHTML +=
  `<tr>
    <td>${k}</td>
    <td>${v}</td>
  </tr>`
})
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: This is great, I can use this and modify the output quite easily I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the complete pathes with the value in arrays.

Basically it take a check for having a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value and an object type but not an array, then get the entries and return an array of the joined keys and the finnal value.

Or return an array of only a nested array with an empty string and the value.

The empty string controls the separation dot for more keys.

```js
const
    getPath = value => value && typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)
        ? Object
            .entries(value)
            .reduce((r, [key, value]) => [
                ...r,
                ...getPath(value).map(([path, value]) => [key + (path && '.') + path, value])
            ], [])
        : [['', value]],
    myObject = { name: 'Dan', age: 31, interests: ['coding', 'asking questions'], needsHelp: true, nestedData: { level1Data: { randomNumber: 41, anObject: { description: 'Nested data' } } } };

console.log(getPath(myObject));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. This is an extremely useful answer. If possible are you able to comment within the code to provide me an idea of exactly what is happening? I feel this will help me gain more understanding and be able to expand upon it further.